# Matching/correcting CRC32 Checksum for modified router firmware

Tags: router, firmware

I've got a Netgear D8500 router which apparently has a wireless IC that doesn't quite match up to the supplied driver firmware. Thus, OOB it works, however whenever there's a firmware update it completely bricks the router because the firmware driver for the WLan IC doesn't take into account this slight IC variation. Very common issue and the router got mothballed.

I'm not entirely clued up on firmware, software, coding etc so please excuse my ignorance, afterall I've come here for help/advice/to learn.

The driver in question is contained within the dhd.ko file in the linux kernel directory in the firmware. Simply put, I've extracted the driver dhd.ko file of a known working firmware for an exactly similar device and replaced the same file in a genuine Netgear firwmare.

The issue is, when it comes to flashing, it fails the CRC32 checksum because obviously, it doesn't match up to the original anymore.

How do I correct this?

[EDIT: For a more visual guide, please see the picture here. The top half is of the PUTTY serial terminal after flashing the modified firmware, the bottom half is of 7Zip CRC32 checksum so I think it's an embedded CRC. Possibly in the header?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Jtk.png)

Comment: How does the router know which CRC32 is correct? Is it embedded in the file itself? Is it a fixed CRC32 value that the manufacturer make sure to create firmwares that match?

Comment: I believe it's embedded in the file itself. Using 7Zip and CRC32 chksum I get 0x62392B09. When uploading the firmware I get "Image chksum: 0xD3ACD13D Calc chksum: 0x0669CF1C so I don't know if it's calculated from the Squashfs volume and then put in the header of the .chk firmware image?

Comment: You should first try to reproduce the CRC32 value of the original firmware. You need to figure out what portions of the file is used to calculate the CRC32 value, and then where the control value is stored. Once you have those pieces you can calculate the CRC32 of your "hacked" firmware and embed the new value in the right place.

Comment: I'll have to look into how to do that as I've never done anything like this before, so there's certainly some learning to be done. That being said, I've just opened the file in a hex editor and that string D3ACD13D only appears twice at the very beginning of the file in both original and edited. I would say it's fairly safe to assume that's where the embeded CRC is? So, could I get away with modifying this HEX to the same as what the device calculated?

Comment: It could be that simple, yes. Be aware though, that if you got any part of your hacking wrong, you might permanently brick your router.

Comment: I'll try it and see how I get on. Technically, the router is bricked anyway because none of the currently available firmwares hold the relevant drivers for this particular revision of IC that was inadvertently used by Foxcon in Vietnam when it was produced for Netgear, bit of an undersight on their behalf. Trouble is as well, whilst this Third party firmware works with the R8500 model, my D8500 model is incompatible because it also includes a VDSL modem, thus different board ID's and won't flash. Hence the need to modify factory firmware.

Comment: Remarkably, that actually worked and the modified firmware flashed. Unfortunately, the router still didn't boot. So there's obviously something else going on that needs further investigation.